# How do I get jQuery Slider Widget to show and fade between images?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I found a concept that is very close to what I need to do: use a slider to fade between images.

Here is the working example on [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/9zqbY/).

Here is my test page: http://energync.ehclients.com/slider.html

I brought the code in but it is not working correctly for me.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="ui-corner-all" id="sliderContent">     
<div class="viewer ui-corner-all">
<div class="content-conveyor ui-helper-clearfix" style="width: 2128px;">

<div class="item">
<h2>Omega Nebula</h2>
<img alt="Omega Nebula" src="http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/377_slider/slider_sourcefiles/images/omega.jpg">
</div>

<div class="item">
<h2>Rosette Nebula</h2>
<img alt="Rosette Nebula" src="http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/377_slider/slider_sourcefiles/images/rosette.jpg">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#sliderContent .item { display: none; position: absolute; }
```

Here is the jQuery

```
$(function() {
$('#sliderContent .item:first').addClass('shown').show();
$("#slider").slider({
value: 0,
min: 0,
max: $('#sliderContent .item').size(),
step: 1
}).bind("slidechange", function(event, ui) {
var newIndex = $("#slider").slider("value");
var oldIndex = $('#sliderContent .item').index('.shown');
if (newIndex != oldIndex) {
$('.shown').fadeOut().removeClass('shown');
$('#sliderContent .item').eq(newIndex).fadeIn().addClass('shown');
}
});
});
```

I would appreciate some help getting this to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle is working fine for me. Do you want the image to change when the user is still holding the slider? (not only when it's released)

Comment: Hi, the fiddle is working fine but i cant get the real file to work. I would like it to change as it is moved, not when released.

Comment: The above code includes the slider event. This is my first time using this widget and I am not real clear on how it is implemented.

Comment: Your code uses the "slidechange" event. Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zqbY/48/).

Comment: Your code works great in Fiddle but it doesn't work correctly in my test page http://energync.ehclients.com/slider.html and I can't figure out what it is missing.

Comment: You are re-including jQuery after including jQuery+UI